# Frameset session problem struts2

Tags: java, session, struts2, frameset

I am passing jsessionid through url. But sessionid keeps changing while using frameset.

Is there any way to keep sessionid in frameset?

Comment: You will probably need to provide more details. Is each frame on the same domain? Have you confirmed that each frame URL contains the JSESSIONID?

Comment: No each frame are not on the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved:

Enabled the cookie in browser. Now it is working fine :)